# How to open Leanback Settings screen on AndroidTV box?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to open Network Settings on android tv box, but using leanback Settings UI, not the mobile one. The android tv box (nexbox) is using AndroidTV launcher.

Currently when I execute

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

it shows this screen:
[image]

but I want to open it and to looks like that:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Borislav, Did you find any way to achieve this?

Comment: @skygeek In the way how it was asked in the question, no. Check Plokko's asnwer. In my case I've build my own Settings screen and I'm redirecting to specific screen like:
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.tv.settings",, class_here)); where for class_here you can put "com.android.tv.settings.device.display.DisplayActivity", "com.android.tv.settings.connectivity.NetworkActivity", "com.android.tv.settings.system.LanguageActivity" and so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Borislav, But I am in need for the same you expected. Will post here if any solution I discover.

Comment: @skygeek When I'd investigate the issue, I've dig into the source code itself. I've checked right now and take a look here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TvSettings/+/718a802/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml?autodive=0#63

If you manage to specify category of the intent I think it will work.

So don't do it with packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage but with intent.setComponent (like in my previous comment) and pass exact package path.

Comment: Thanks :) But it didn't work :(

Comment: Hi @Borislav, I figure out that we need to build our own settings using GuidedStepFragment in leanback that fulfils our purpose.

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
try {
                    ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.android.tv.settings",
                            "com.android.tv.settings.connectivity.NetworkActivity");
                    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    i.setComponent(name);

                    startActivity(i);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Timber.e(e);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the only solution i fould so far is to call the Android tv settings app directly (it would be better to find a dedicated intent but so far i found nothing)

```
val LaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.tv.settings")
startActivity(LaunchIntent)
```

Just to be safe you can catch a RuntimeException and start the default settings if the package is not found:

```
try {
    val LaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.tv.settings")
    startActivity(LaunchIntent)
}catch(e:RuntimeException){
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
}
```

**Note: this code is written in Kotlin but it's pretty simple to convert in Java**

Comment: Did you find any piece of code that open tv setting of display option direction via intent ?